# How did Edward break the mirror lock in The Order?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-order

In episode 8 of *The Order* Edward activates the vade mecum, and its previous owner appears. They perform a mirror lock spell so that any injury done to one of them happens to both of them.

Edward then stabs himself in the heart. The other guy dies from the injury, but Edward stands up uninjured. How did he do that? Why didn't he die from the stab wound as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the binding spell, if any one of them dies the spell gets broken.

This is the conversation between Edward Coventry and the book owner:

> *Edward picks up the knife*
>
> Book Owner: Ah, ah, ah, ah! Remember the mirror incantation.
>
> Book Owner: You hurt me, you're only hurting yourself.
>
> Edward: Exactly.
>
> *Edward stabs himself*
>
> Book Owner: Sanetur! Reparetur! Restituatur!
>
> Edward: See?
>
> Edward: Here's the thing about a mirror incantation. It only mimics the injuries. It doesn't guarantee certain death.
>
> Edward: You never should have threatened my son.
>
> Book Owner: You killed yourself... for petty revenge?
>
> Edward: All I have to do is outlive you.
>
> Book Owner: You want everything the Vade Maecum offers... but you'll never be able to pay the price.
>
> Edward: You can die thinking that.
>
> Book Owner: You will never be able to sacrifice your own son.
>
> *Book owner dies*
>
> *Edward removes the knife and heals himself*

The mirror incantation doesn't guarantee certain death, it only mimics the injuries... So both of them have the exact same injuries, but they might not die at the exact same time. Once he was sure the book owner was dead, the spell got broken, and he healed himself.

Comment: But then there's another guy there, and edward says something about him being responsible for him living? If the book owner couldn't heal himself, why could edward?

Comment: The book owner couldn't heal himself because if he did that he would also be healing edward.... And the knife was in him so that isn't possible. The other guy there just gave his body to the book owner...

Comment: I guess what I'm really getting at, is why the book guy died first, and the other guy came back to life afterwards. But maybe there isn't an answer.